# How can I retrieve all files in a specific folder?

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I found this as a solution, but it didn't work for me:

> $optParams = array(
>           'pageSize' => 10,
>           'fields' => "nextPageToken, files(contentHints/thumbnail,fileExtension,iconLink,id,name,size,thumbnailLink,webContentLink,webViewLink,mimeType,parents)",
>           'q' => "'".$folderId."' in parents"
>           );   $results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);

Here is my code:

> $client->setClientSecret('xxxxxx');
>   $client->setRedirectUri('https://wosbc.com/oauth2callback.php');
>   $client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/readonly');
>   $client->setAccessType('offline'); $client->setPrompt('consent');
>
> $credentialsPath = "credentials.json";
>
> if (file_exists("credentials.json")) {
>       $access_token = (file_get_contents("credentials.json"));
>       $client->setAccessToken($access_token);
>       //Refresh the token if it's expired.
>       if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired())  {       echo "accesstoken is expired
> ";
>           $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
>           file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));      echo "saved
>   getAccessToken
> ";
>       }
>       $drive_service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
>       //$mp3array = $drive_service->files->listFiles(array())->getFiles(); works, but not
>   listing by folder         $folderid = "xxxxxxxxx";
>     $optParams = array(
>           'pageSize' => 10,
>           'fields' => "id, name",
>           'q' => "'".$folderId."' in parents"
>           ); $mp3array = $drive_service->files->listFiles($optParams);

Sorry for the way the code formatted. This produced the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: { "error": { "errors":
>   [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "notFound", "message": "File not
>   found: .", "locationType": "parameter", "location": "fileId" } ],
>   "code": 404, "message": "File not found: ." } } in
>   /home/wosbccom/public_html/google-api-php-client-2.4.1/src/Google/Http/REST.php:119
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/wosbccom/public_html/google-api-php-client-2.4.1/src/Google/Http/REST.php(94):
>   Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response),
>   Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...') #1
>   /home/wosbccom/public_html/google-api-php-client-2.4.1/src/Google/Task/Runner.php(176):
>   Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client),
>   Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...') #2
>   /home/wosbccom/public_html/google-api-php-client-2.4.1/src/Google/Http/REST.php(58):
>   Google_Task_Runner->run() #3
>   /home/wosbccom/public_html/google-api-php-client-2.4.1/src/Google/Client.php(842):
>   Google_Http_REST::execute(Object( in
>   /home/wosbccom/public_html/google-api-php-client-2.4.1/src/Google/Http/REST.php
>   on line 119

Can you tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: In your script, `$folderid = "xxxxxxxxx";` is declared as `$folderid`. But `$folderId` is used at `'q' => "'".$folderId."' in parents"`. I think that this spelling mistake between `i` and `I` is the reason of your current error message. Can you test your script by modifying this? By this, if the error message is not removed or changed, I apologize.

Comment: Tanaike! That did the trick. Thank you so much for the help. I don't know how to give you official credit for this, but you gave the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your script, $folderid = "xxxxxxxxx"; is declared as $folderid. But $folderId is used at 'q' => "'".$folderId."' in parents". I think that this spelling mistake between i and I is the reason of your current error message. Can you test your script by modifying this?

In your script, `$folderid = "xxxxxxxxx";` is declared as `$folderid`. But `$folderId` is used at `'q' => "'".$folderId."' in parents"`. I think that this spelling mistake between `i` and `I` is the reason of your current error message.

Please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
$folderid = "xxxxxxxxx";
```

#### To:

```
$folderId = "xxxxxxxxx";
```

or

#### From:

```
'q' => "'".$folderId."' in parents
```

#### To:

```
'q' => "'".$folderid."' in parents
```

Comment: In my report, in the current stage, it seems that `'###folderId###' in parents`, `parents = '###folderId###'`, and `parents in '###folderId###'` can be used for retrieving the file list by the search query. https://tanaikech.github.io/2021/04/27/specification-of-search-query-for-file-list-method-in-drive-api/